# Analyse of power recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I want to write power recursive function that it's analyse is o(n):
This is my idea
is it true??
Or if the analyse of this code is not o(n) can anyone help me to change it to make it better??
thanks in advance

```
  power(int x , int n)
  {
      if(n==0)
        return 1;
      else
        return x*power(x,n-1);
  }
```

Comment: It *is* linear time, but it's possible to write a pow() function that takes logarithmic time. Try searching for "repeated squaring".

Comment: Well, for starters, power(n, 0) would be 1, not n. Special case when n = 0, which is undefined.

Comment: It should be Theta(k)

Comment: It is linear with respect to k

Comment: it is example of `tail-recursion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is O(n) time because you are counting down from the input n to where n is 0.

Comment: O(n), you are contradicting yourself ?

Comment: No, it is not O(n), it's O(k).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. Power of N to 0 is 1. This must be constant O(1).
2. Power of N to 1 is N. This also must be constant O(1).

After that, the code should work. It will behave in linear time for the power, so it will be O(k).

Answer (score 1):

This method is O(k), not O(n), because it will perform `k` recursive calls.  Additionally, the base case `k` being `0` should return `1`, not `n`.

Comment: Usually you say O(N) to refer to linear time. But yes, this algorithm is linear to `k` variable and not to `n` variable.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, usually, `n` is used.  In this question, `n` is a different variable.  I see you corrected it in your answer, from O(n) to O(k).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function recursively "k+1" times. Example for power(10,3), you make the following function calls

```
power(10,3)  -
power(10,2)   |  k+1 times
power(10,1)   |
power(10,0)  -
```

Thus the complexity is O(k) and not O(n) !

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "k" times your function and its upper bound matches with its lower bound. So i think it's Theta(k)